# Does MX Record forward or redirect?

Tags: email-server, web-hosting, mx-record

I have a simple question on how MX Records work. When I enter an external mail server address (e.g. to Google Suite/Mail) in my hosts control panel, do mail get redirected (meaning not saved first) or forwarded (saved, and then sent to Google)? If this depends on the hosts server setup, please let me know that as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MX records are essentially signposts for email delivery - emails are never stored by intermediate servers, only forwarded to their final destination. So, in your words, the mails are *redirected*, however the terms *redirected* and *forwarded* can be used interchangeably when dealing with email.

Generally speaking, when you send an email, the receiving server (e.g. your ISP's mail relay) checks the recipient domain and looks up the MX records for that domain. The email is then forwarded to those MX servers for delivery to the recipient.

This doesn't mean that the email may not be saved *temporarily* in some form or another, for example for spam checking, buffering in case the destination mail server is unavailable, but relay servers should never permanently store email.

Comment: Some MTAs/MDAs do buffer mail, though (of course not the _MX_ _records_, but the intermediate or frontend MTAs/MDAs to which these MX records are assigned).

Comment: I understand MX records enough now I think. The support at my web host however say that they can recover my mail although I use a 3rd party provider (like Google). If the MX records are pointed at Google, it seems with my understanding that it actually should be "impossible" to recover mail. The reason I'm checking is since it will be a company domain I want redundancy for tax declaration reasons.

Comment: @Jonke-Pö that's correct - your web-host seems to be under the impression that you are using their servers for receiving your email. You are correct - if your MX servers are pointed at Google (and Google is where your emails are stored), your web-host would not be able to recover any email.

Answer (score 2):

When you send an Email, your mail server does a DNS lookup looking for the MX record for the domain you are trying to email, the MX record identifies the servers responsible for delivering email to that domain. Once your Mail server has obtained the MX record it does another DNS lookup looking for the IP Address of the Mail server identified in the MX record. Once it has the IP Address of the remote mail server it then uses SMTP to establish a connection to the remote mail server and then it sends the email.

For more details see the link below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record